# How can I fix the warning I'm getting with loading my ArrayList to JList?

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jlist

I'm getting a warning with line 53:
list = new JList(alCar.toArray());

The warning reads:
Assignment to UI-bound field will overwrite field generated by UI Designer. 
This inspection reports assignments to fields which are bound to components in UI Designer forms.  Such assignments will cause the component setup code generated by UI Designer for such fields to be ignored.

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CarApp {
    private JButton btnDelObj;
    private JButton btnAddObj;
    private DefaultListModel dlm;
    private JList list;
    private JPanel panelMain;
    private ArrayList<Car> alCar;
    private String sMake, sModel, newYear, fileName;
    private int iYear;

public CarApp() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    alCar = new ArrayList<>();
    list = new JList();
    list.setModel(dlm);

    //Sorts the ArrayList Car objects by model in alphabetical order.
    Collections.sort(alCar, new Comparator<Car>() {
        public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
            if (o1.model.compareToIgnoreCase(o2.model) == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (o1.model.compareToIgnoreCase(o2.model) < 0) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });

    //Loads the file specified by the user
    loadFile();

    //Adds a JList to the GUI with the ArrayList loaded from binary file
    list = new JList(alCar.toArray());
    list.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    list.setVisible(true);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.add(new JScrollPane());

    //JList selection event
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            list.getSelectedIndex();
        }
    });

    //btnAddObj click event
    btnAddObj.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sMake = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the maker of the car: ");
            sModel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the model of the car: ");
            newYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year of the car: ");
            iYear = Integer.parseInt(newYear);

            //Add new Car object to the ArrayList
            alCar.add(new Car(sMake, sModel, iYear));

            //This serializes a file
            //saveFile();

            //Notifies the ListDataListeners when changes occur in ArrayList<Car>
            for (int i = 0; i < alCar.size(); i++) {
                dlm.addElement(alCar.get(i));
            }
            list.setModel(dlm);
        }
    });

    //btnDelObj Click Event
    btnDelObj.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = (dlm.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                dlm.remove(list.getSelectedIndex());
                //alCar.remove(list.getSelectedIndex());
            }
            list.setModel(dlm);
        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cars");
    CarApp myApp = new CarApp();
    frame.setContentPane(myApp.panelMain);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

//This serializes a file
public void saveFile() {
    try {
        fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the file you want to save to: ");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(alCar);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Serialized data is saved in " + fileName);

    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A problem occurred with serialization." +
                "Make sure that the file you're saving to is in the same directory as your project." +
                "Hence, a peer to your src folder.");

    }
}

//This deserializes a file. I wasn't able to get the sorting to work after deserialization. It was working prior to this.
public void loadFile() {
    try {
        fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the file you want to open: ");
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        alCar = (ArrayList<Car>) in.readObject();
        for (int index = 0; index < alCar.size(); index++) {
            System.out.println(alCar.get(index).toString());

        }
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();

    } catch (IOException i) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A problem occurred during deserialization.");
        i.printStackTrace();
        return;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Car class not found.");
        c.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }
}
}

//This class describes Car objects
class Car implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String make;
    String model;
    private int year;

/**
 * Constructor that accepts arguments from the Car object for make, model, and year.
 *
 * @param make  The maker of the car
 * @param model The model of the car
 * @param year  The year of the car
 */

public Car(String make, String model, int year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;

}

//This method describes the state (data that is stored in the object's fields at any moment)
//of the Car object.
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(Make: " + make + ", Model: " + model + ", Year: " + year + ")";
}
}
```

Comment: Is it intentional that your CarApp constructor construct an empty `alCar` list and sort an empty list?

Comment: Hi there, I already have a serialized file containing some car objects. It is called cars.ser within my src folder.

Comment: Your CarApp() constructor looks wrong to start with. Also why use Object serialization? Is it something you want to learn? I would not go down that path...however that is not the question your asking. The warning you saw, is it Java that printed that or the IDE? What you expected to see if you assign an Array of Car to a JList? I guess it use the `toString()` method to display make:model of each car?

Comment: Yes, object serialization is something that I need to know.  The warning came from clicking on the alCar.toArray() part.  So I think that's from the IDE? Yes I just wanted the JList to print out multiple car objects with the display of the toString() method.

Comment: Try run the app in the console, outside the IDE? Another thing to try is `list = new JList<Car>(alCar.toArray());` or `list = new JList<Car>(alCar.toArray(new Car[]{}));`

Comment: list = new JList<Car>(alCar.toArray(new Car[]{})); gave me no warnings at the line I put it in the constructor. However, now I'm getting a warning for lines 153:  alCar = (ArrayList<Car>) in.readObject();
, 50: loadFile();
 , and 119:  CarApp myApp = new CarApp();

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDE by the way

Comment: I would say its just a "warning!" however I would say do not use object serialisation the way you have done it. As you can see, if you changed your Car class then all previous serialised objects become unserialisable. I think the reason for the warning is because Java sees that casting to a generic type is unsafe. Serialization works well when your streaming between tiers in temporary state, short live object.